# Speeding up compilation of Delphi 7 application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I started a new job a few months ago where the whole business relies on Delphi 7-built applications and interfaces to external systems and partners. A lot of 3rd party components are used, such as the whole DevExpress library, Indy, TMS components, Turbopower, SDAC, and many more, for a total of about 20.

This is the state of things and none of it can be changed (the company has over 1000 employees).

Now, compiling their main application takes around 7 minutes and has over 2M lines of code. All the workstations run on VMWare, which might account for part of the compile time. This compile time is the same, even when server/network load is minimal at night.

Changing a single line of code will cause a simple compile to take 4 to 5 minutes, even if nothing else changed. I cannot use code completion or code parameters is impractical as it incurs a delay about as long as a compile.

Is there anything I could do to improve compile time? I ran some ideas by the manager, and DLLs or any type of external dependencies are out of the question. Upgrading to a newer version of Delphi is out of the question as they estimated that cost to over half a million dollars, and they plan to do that at a much later date.

Someone mentioned putting all 3rd party files in their own separate packages since they never change, but I'm not experienced with packages enough to know if that would help compile times.

I did some searching over the last few weeks, but I did not find any ideas that would apply to my situation.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

PS: I need to add that I tried DelphiSpeedUp and other tools with no help in compile times.

Comment: Is the source code stored on a network share? That would slow down the compilation a lot.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasHausladen: We were once able to reduce the compile time from about 8 minutes to a mere 20 seconds just by copying all sources and precompiled DCUs from a network share to the local drive.

Comment: Wow Uwe, that's a huge gain. Yes, we are all through the network and using virtual machines on top of that which is why I probably will be having a hard time finding any help. --EDIT: I was wrong. The files are checked out on our VM's disks. Which is still a VM through a network...

Comment: "a VM through a network" If you can't change that, you could consider a RAM disk in the VM for the source code if you have enough RAM available. But that should be only a last resort.

Comment: I have much more ram than I use. I will give this a try monday for sure!

Comment: I would start to test the case where you try to compile everything local, on a local machine, no VM involved, etc. Just to see how long it would take to compile in that situation.

Comment: Packages are DLLs. So if you can't use DLLs then you can't use packages. There are many good reasons why a monolithic executable is a good idea. All that said, changes in the implementation section only should not trigger mass recompile. You should have your source on local SSD drives, 64 bit OS with lots of RAM.

Comment: @EricFortier Based on what you have written in your question and your comments it seems that your problem is not compilation time but instead linking time. And best way for improving linking time in Delphi is to lower the number of items that are being linked. And yes you can achieve this by compiling multiple units into one package so that in the end linker doesn't have to link each compiled unit separately but can link just one library which contain multiple units.

Comment: @EricFortier Also avoid having your source code or your compiled units on network drive at all times. Why? Transferring multiple of small files over network is much slower than when you are transferring one big file. You can observe this by trying to copy 10000 smaller let us say 100 KB sized files or copying one 100 MB file over network.

Comment: @EricFortier As for keeping al the source code localy. If you company still isn't using some `Source controls` which allows synching code across multiple computers it is about the time you start using it. God `Source control` can have a great beneficial impact on work performance especially if your company has many developers.

Comment: Are you recompiling any/all of the third party libraries each time? Or do you have pre-compiled dcu's for all third party components, and have the appropriate folders  in the library path _before_ the source code folders? (I have had to fix this problem in a large codebase before)